# Using generics in ArrayList (Java, "cannot be applied" error)

Tags: java, android, list, generics, collections

In my Android Studio project I have simple structure of classes:

```
public class P{}

public class A extends P{}

public class B extends P{}
```

And in another class I have a List:

```
private List<? extends P> data;
private List<A> listA;
private List<B> listB;
```

But when I try to do that:

```
data = listA; //it's ok
data.addAll(listB); //it calls error
```

The second line is red in Android Studio and error is:

```
addAll(java.util.Collection<capture<? extends com.mydomain.P>>) 
in List cannot be applied to (java.util.List<com.mydomain.subclass.B>)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The compiler can't let you add any type to a list it doesn't know the type of. Basically, if you don't know the type, ie. you have `?`, you can't use that type.

Comment: [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Answer (score 5):

When you declare `private List<? extends P> data;` You require a specific type that extends p for the content of your list, which is not necessary. You can simply use:

```
private List<P> data;
```

As any class that extends `P` (B and A alike) will be accepted.

(That prevent you from assigning `data = listA`, though)

Answer (score 3):

When you use a parameterized type like `List`, the compiler does some type binding and type checking at compilation time.

So with a variable declared as

```
List<A> listA;
```

any use of `listA` will be with the type argument `A`.

With a variable declared as

```
List<?> data;
```

any use of `data` will be with the type argument `?` which is the wildcard, but the actual type is unknown.

Given that it doesn't know the actual type, the compiler can't let you make use of it. The `add(E)` method of `List` depends on the type variable. So

```
List<A> listA = ...;
listA.add(someA);
```

would be fine since `someA` is of type `A`.

Now you may think

```
List<?> data = listA;
data.add(someA); // theoretically fine
```

should word, but like this

```
List<?> data = someMethod();
data.add(someA);
```

it doesn't. What if the referenced `List` isn't meant to hold `A` objects?

The compiler simply can't allow this. That is what type-checking all about with generics.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one if you are using `ArrayList` only.

```
public class P {}

public class A extends P {}

public class B extends P {}

public class MyList<T extends P> extends ArrayList<P> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ...
}

private static MyList<? extends P> data;
private static MyList<A> listA;
private static MyList<B> listB;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    data = listA; // it's ok
    data.addAll(listB); // it's ok
}
```

Comment: Careful, this isn't the same thing. It would be if you had `ArrayList<T>` rather than `<P>`.

Comment: but `T extends P`. What is the issue in it.

Comment: But I want to know what the issue in this way?

Comment: In their example, the `addAll` method depends on the type variable `E` declared in `List`. The compiler binds `? extends P` to that type variable when they declare `List<? extends P>`. In your example, you declare a different type `MyList` with a type variable `T`, but the `addAll` method inherited from `ArrayList` depends on `P`, not on `T`. So in your declaration of `MyList<? extends P>` and then `data.addAll`, the `addAll` isn't looking at `?`, it's looking at `P`.

Comment: Its giving me compilation error if I use `ArrayList<T>`. `The method addAll(Collection<? extends capture#2-of ? extends TestDemo.P>) in the type ArrayList<capture#2-of ? extends TestDemo.P> is not applicable for the arguments 
 (TestDemo.MyList<TestDemo.B>)`

Comment: Exactly, that would be the same thing OP gets. You've changed the situation. You're no longer explaining OP's problem, but a different one.

Comment: I think there is no issue in using `ArrayList<P>` because `T extends P`.

Comment: I'm not saying there's an issue. Your code will compile fine. But it is not a good example or demonstration of what OP is doing nor does it explain why they get an exception. It's a completely different situation.